# Array initialization with structures

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14, initializer-list

I have the following data structures

```
struct single_t
{
    uint16_t i1 = 0;
    uint8_t i2 = 0;
    uint8_t i3 = 0;
};

struct mapping_t
{
    uint8_t n1;
    uint8_t n2;
    bool enable;
    uint n3;
    std::array<single_t, 32> map;
};
```

I want to initialize them in the following way:

```
mapping_t m1 {
    3,                                  // n1
    254,                                // n2
    true,                               // enable
    5,                                  // n3

    // map
    // i1                   i2              i3
    {{
        {0x1000,            1,              8}
    }}
};
```

can i be sure, that the elements in the `std::array<single_t, 32> map;`, in this case indexes 1..31, are initialized to 0 or is it like the uninitialized variable on the stack `int i;` ? My debugger shows they are at 0, but is that implementation dependent on the debug build or is this defined in the standard?

Comment: The elements 1 - 31 of `m1` are value initialized, i.e. initialized to zero in your case. Your code is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members or
>   initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members are 
>   value-initialized. If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed.

The default case for value initialization is to initialize with 0

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

> The effects of value initialization are:
>
> [...]
>
> 4) otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

To sumarize, you're fine !